# Force create directories for temporary file and path in Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, temporary-files, temporary-directory

I have a C# Windows Phone 8 app where I need to create some temporary files.  Currently I'm creating the necessary temporary file name and path using the following code:

```
string tempFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetTempFileName());
Uri tempUri = new Uri(tempFilename, UriKind.Absolute);
```

The problem is, when I go to create the file with the following code:

```
StorageFile binaryFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

The operation fails with a file not found Exception because the folder path does not exist yet.  How do I quickly create all the necessary directories and sub-directories beneath it to support the temporary file path, in a manner that doesn't fail if the directory tree already exists?

Here's a sample temporary file name and path:

```
C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\{28B80680-CB2F-459B-B6AC-A60A9A729868}\Temp\tmp7C9F.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to create directory in isolated storage: [IsolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.createdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you are in windows phone